# How to check the existence of multiple directories?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script which obviously faulty:

```
if [ -d "$BACKUP/${DATE_MAX}_"* ]
  then
    ...
fi
```

This script would only work if there is a single or no directory there at all. If there are multiple directories like _1  it will break with:

> functions.sh: line 93: [: too many arguments

How could I check the existence of multiple directories then call delete on the directories one by one?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the only thing you're trying to do is delete directories that match that pattern, you could use:

```
rm -r "$BACKUP/${DATE_MAX}"_*
```

If you're trying to do additional stuff, you could use:

```
cd "$BACKUP"
for filename in ${DATE_MAX}_*
do
    # Stuff you want to do
    rm -r "$filename"
done
```

Comment: `$(ls ...)` isn't required, the shell will expand `${DATE_MAX}_*` correctly in it's own.

Comment: Very good point. I've edited for simplicity.